# Set the size of a custom component not working?

Tags: java

I want to have my two argument constructor be able to accept two parameters and then to set the size of the JComponent for me. I have receiving errors when I do this at the current time. Why would that be the case. I override the method and the call the setSize method from in size the setSize but I think that it cause a stackoverflow be cause of a recursive call over and over again.

**How do I implement the setSize(...) in my personal component so that I can have someone set the size of my component?**

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JComponent;

public class MyComponent extends JComponent {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    MyComponent() {
        super();
    }

    MyComponent(int x, int y) {
        Dimension d = new Dimension(x,y);
        this.setSize(d);
    }

    @Override
    public void setSize(Dimension d) {
        setSize(d);
    }

//  @Override
//  public void setSize(int x, int y) {
//      Dimension d = new Dimension(x,y);
//      setSize(d);
//  }

    @Override
    public Dimension getSize() {
        return this.getSize();
    }

    @Override
    public void setPreferredSize(Dimension d) {
        this.setPreferredSize(d);
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize () {
         return new Dimension(100, 25);
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawLine(10, 10, 100, 100);
    }

    public void paintBorder(Graphics g) {
        super.paintBorder(g);
        g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, 50, 50);
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.drawRect(0, 0, 50, 50);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);
        paintComponent(g);
        paintBorder(g);
        paintChildren(g);
    }
}
    }
```

Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at testpak.MyComponent.setSize(MyComponent.java:23)
    at testpak.MyComponent.setSize(MyComponent.java:23)
    at testpak.MyComponent.setSize(MyComponent.java:23)
    at testpak.MyComponent.setSize(MyComponent.java:23)
    at testpak.MyComponent.setSize(MyComponent.java:23)
    ...etc...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 @Override
    public void setSize(Dimension d) {
        super.setSize(d);
    }
```

do you mean this?

Answer (score 0):

Your immediate problem is that your setSize() method does nothing but call itself. It will continue doing so until the stack runs out of space. Why did you override the method? Either remove your override or use super.setSize() inside if you're planning to do something in addition.

BTW, there is more to controlling component size than simply setting its size. The biggest thing is the layout manager used by the frame/component containing the component may be setting your component's size according to its rules. I'm guessing that is the root of your problems...

Comment: // @Override
// public void setSize(int x, int y) {
//  super.setSize(new Dimension(x,y));
// }
  This is the one that gives me an error.                    at testpak.MyComponent.setSize(MyComponent.java:28)
 at java.awt.Component.resize(Component.java:2195)
 at java.awt.Component.setSize(Component.java:2186)
 at testpak.MyComponent.setSize(MyComponent.java:28)
 at java.awt.Component.resize(Component.java:2195)

Comment: Do you have a link that shows a JComponent that has been created that really works nice?

Comment: @Doug Swing is great, but it has a big learning curve. Check out the Swing Tutorial http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/. Your question is covered in Laying Out Components Within a Container, but you should go through the whole thing. It will end up saving you time and a lot of frustration.